# Give a formal derivation of ∃x~P(y) given the premises ~∃x(∀yP(y) ∧ Q(x)) and Q(b)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

This is one of the question I was given for homework, and I'm not sure how to do it, I'm not even really sure how to start. I missed some classes, and I've been trying to figure it out for a couple hours, but still haven't gotten anywhere.

**Edit 1**:
so I've come up with this, however I’m not very confident about it

> 1. ~∃x(∀yP(y)$\wedge$Q(x))
> 2. Q(b)
> 3. ∀x~(∀yP(y)$\wedge$Q(x))  1, change to universal quantification
> 4. ∀x~(∀yP(y))          3, specialization
> 5. ~(∀yP(y))            4, U.I.
> 6. ∃y~P(y)              5, change to existential quantification

Comment: What is " /\"?  Conjunction?  Also, if you use universal instantiation, you probably should switch from a letter used for variables to a letter used for some constant.

Answer (score 1):

If we are asked to provide a formal derivation, it's always relevant to know the rules you are asked to use. I'm assuming here you are using standard FOL **natural deduction** calculus. The proof then goes as follows:

> 1. $\neg \exists x (\forall y P(y) \wedge Q(x))$, P
> 2. $Q(b)$, P
> 3. $\forall x \neg (\forall y P(y) \wedge Q(x))$, 1 $\exists$def
> 4. $ \neg (\forall y P(y) \wedge Q(b)$ 3 $\forall$E (UI)
> 5. $\neg \forall y P(y) \vee \neg Q(b)$ 4 De Morgan Laws
> 6. $\neg \forall y P(y)$ 5 Disjunctive Syllogism
> 7. $\exists y \neg P(y)$ 6 $\exists$def

As you can see I'm assuming some propositional admissible rules, namely, the **De Morgan Laws** and **Disjunctice Syllogism**, hoping that you can complete it as the rest of your homework.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard without knowing what rules of inference you are allowed to use ...

Assuming that we can use the equivalences between $\forall \lnot$ and $\lnot \exists$ and between $\lnot \forall$ and $\exists \lnot$ and [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws), we have first to rewrite the formula :

> $\lnot ∃x(∀yP(y) \land Q(x))$

as : $∀x \lnot (∀yP(y) \land Q(x))$ which is equivalent to $∀x (\lnot ∀yP(y) \lor \lnot Q(x))$ and finally to :

> $∀x (∃y \lnot P(y) \lor \lnot Q(x))$.

---

Now for the derivation :

*1)* $∀x (∃y \lnot P(y) \lor \lnot Q(x))$ --- premise [1] (after the transformation)

*2)* $Q(b)$ --- premise [2]

*3)* $∃y \lnot P(y) \lor \lnot Q(b)$ --- from [1] by $\forall$E (i.e. **UI**)

*4)* $∃y \lnot P(y)$ --- assumed [2]

*5)* $\lnot Q(b)$ --- assumed [3]

*6)* $\bot$ --- from 2) and 5) by $\rightarrow$E (or *modus ponens*)

*7)* $∃y \lnot P(y)$ --- from 6) by $\bot$E

> *8)* $∃y \lnot P(y)$ --- from 3), 4), 5) and 7) by $\lor$E, discharging assumptions [2] and [3]

*Conclusion* from 1), 2) and 8) :

> > $\lnot ∃x(∀yP(y) \land Q(x)), Q(b) \vdash ∃y \lnot P(y)$.

---

*Note*

In the derivation I have use *natural deduction*; if your *proof system* is different, you have to adapt the above proof to it.

For example, the above derivation can be easily adapted to an *Hilbert-style* proof, using again De Morgan and the equivalences between quantifiers.

We have to start from premise 1 :

> $\lnot ∃x(∀yP(y) \land Q(x))$

and apply De Morgan "inside" to get :

$\lnot ∃x \lnot (\lnot ∀yP(y) \lor \lnot Q(x))$

which is :

$\forall x(\exists y \lnot P(y) \lor \lnot Q(x))$.

Now we instantiate the universal quantifier, to get :

$\exists y \lnot P(y) \lor \lnot Q(b)$

and use the equivalence between $\lnot p \lor q$ and $p \rightarrow q$ to rewrite it as :

$Q(b) \rightarrow \exists y \lnot P(y)$.

The conclusion follows from premise 2 and *modus ponens*.